# Find a real numbers $u,v$ such that $p(u)<0$ and $p(v)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ where are $a,b$ and $c$ are real number .Find a real numbers $u,v$ such that $p(u)<0$ and $p(v)>0$

since this odd degree polynomial so it has at least one root we cal prove by intermediate value theorem

so this function $p(x)$ at least on real root

but how to find $u,v$ such that $p(u)<0$ and $p(v)>0$

Thank you.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u > 0$ and $u > -3a$, $u^2 > -3b$ and $u^3 > -3c$.  Then we have $p(u) > 0$.
Similarly suppose $v < 0$ and $v < -3a$, $v^2 > 3b$ and $v^3 < -3c$.
Then we have $p(v) < 0$.

Comment: How can we say that $u>-3a$ if a is negative

Comment: Why not?  For example, if $a = -2$ this says $u > 6$.

Comment: what if a is positive

Comment: Then the $u > 0$ is stronger than $u > -3a$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that
\begin{align}
p(x)= x^3+ax^2+bx+c = x^3\left( 1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{x^2}+\frac{c}{x^3}\right) \approx x^3
\end{align}
when $|x|\gg 1$.